# OpenShift / OKD single node cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

I am playing with community version of OpenShift (OKD) version 4.7. I deployed it on AWS with no problem. Though, it needs 5 nodes. Is there way to launch everything on one single node?

I am looking at the [documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-customizations.html) but I am not seeing how this can be achieved. Maybe setting the number of master replicas to 1 and the number of worker replicas to 0 would do the trick? CRC is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, June 20th, single node doesn't work with any version after 4.5. I tested with 4.5 in AWS and got excellent result. As of June 25th, OKD 4.8. also supports single node with IPI on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

CodeReady Containers aka crc is what you're looking for https://github.com/code-ready/crc (or Minishift for 3.x).

Comment: Sorry. I did indeed say I am not interested in CRC.

Comment: Why not? That's the only option they provide AFAIK.